# Summerizing a table in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

```
proc sql;
update summary tmp1
set E_1ST_CLICK_DT = min (tmp1.E_1ST_CLICK_DT, (select E_1ST_CLICK_DT from CLICK_SUMM tmp2
                    where tmp1.card_number = tmp2.card_number
                        and tmp1.package_sk = tmp2.package_sk))
where exists (select 1 from CLICK_SUMM tmp2
                    where tmp1.card_number = tmp2.card_number
                        and tmp1.package_sk = tmp2.package_sk
            )
;
quit;
```

I want to get the 1st click date from the click summary table and populate it in summary table. Unfortunately I can't do a update on left join since sas doesn't support it. Is there a better way to do this than shown above since this is not really an efficient way of doing it? Can we use data step instead?

EDIT:
Summary and click_summ tables are in Oracle.

Comment: Would be helpful to see your table structure.  SAS does support a left join:  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/65065/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1bk7i6jqseje7n1lifcip8kzhpp.htm

Comment: Left join is supported but not update with left join.

Comment: Is click_summary already unique by card_number or does it have many records per card_number?  Does summary already have e_1st_click_dt in it, or is it initially empty?  How large are the two tables?

Comment: click_summ is unique by card_number and package_sk.
e_1st_click_dt in summary may be empty(null) or can have a date.
click_summ is small table but summary is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this in SAS.  A double set statement works well for left joins in a data step.

I assume you are not wanting to put nulls from E_1ST_CLICK_DT.  If that is incorrect, let me know.

1. Filter out the null values you don't want
2. Add an index on the CLICK_SUMM table for the keys.
3. Double Set to join on the values.

This offers a single pass through the large table and random access into the smaller table.

```
data temp(index=(comp=(card_number package_sk)));
set click_summ(where=(^missing(e_1st_click_dt)));
keep card_number package_sk e_1st_click_dt;
run;

data summary(drop=new_date) ;
set summary;
set temp(rename=(e_1st_click_dt= new_date) in=a) key=comp;
if a then do;
   e_1st_click_dt = min(e_1st_click_dt,new_date);
end;
else
   _ERROR_ = 0; /*No need for IORC errors*/
run;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Let me try it out.

Comment: A quick question. Summary table is the larger table, so I would have assumed that the index should have been on that table and not on the click_summ. Can you please tell me why this is not so?

Comment: because the index is used for random access.  You don't want to randomly access the big table.  The smaller table can be accessed faster.  That's why you loop over the big table once while using RA on the smaller.  Also, creating the index on the big table can be done, but it will take a while to create and take up disk space.  Unless you need it for picking out values, don't bother to create it.

Comment: Do you have a work around if the summary is an Oracle table. An error comes: Table cannot be replaced, the engine doesnt support this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138104/error-in-modify-statement-in-data-step-ora-01403 Can you please comment?