# Update an oracle table with data from another table in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to run the following piece of code to update table summary from data in click_summ table.

```
data temp(index=(comp=(card_number package_sk)));
set click_summ(where=(^missing(e_1st_click_dt)));
keep card_number package_sk e_1st_click_dt;
run;

data summary(drop=new_date) ;
set summary;
set temp(rename=(e_1st_click_dt= new_date) in=a) key=comp;
if a then do;
   e_1st_click_dt = min(e_1st_click_dt,new_date);
end;
else
   _ERROR_ = 0; /*No need for IORC errors*/
run;
```

This particular piece of code is throwing an error saying:

> ERROR: The ORACLE table SUMMARY has been opened for OUTPUT. This table already exists, or  there is a name conflict 
>         with an existing object. This table will not be replaced. This engine does not  support the REPLACE option.

What is the work around for the same? This question is related to a question I raised earlier ([Summerizing a table in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943101/summerizing-a-table-in-sas))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data temp;
set click_summ(where=(^missing(e_1st_click_dt)));
keep card_number package_sk e_1st_click_dt;
run;

data summary(drop=new_date) ;
modify summary temp(rename=(e_1st_click_dt= new_date) in=a);
by card_number, package_sk;
if a then do;
   e_1st_click_dt = min(e_1st_click_dt,new_date);
end;
else
   _ERROR_ = 0; /*No need for IORC errors*/
run;
```

Modify was the key. This will work fine with Oracle tables as well. And pretty fast too.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the table name from summary to something else and try..am not sure whether we can use summary as a table name since proc summary is there...not sure but try and see

Comment: Actual name is not summary. But that is not the cause. My requirement is to update the same table, hence changing the table name will not solve my problem either :\

Answer (score 0):

As error-message says, you can't replace oracle table in DATA-step. The workaround of it would be:

1) To do all data manipulations in an interim SAS-dataset;

2) Delete all rows in an original Oracle table using PROC SQL ... DELETE ...;

3) Add new data (interim dataset)  to empty Oracle table using PROC APPEND.

Comment: This is the solution I had to start with. But was scared by the fact that there is a delete that is happening and what if the append failed?!

Comment: Well, that's what are backups for. As an alternative to deleting you can try UPDATE inside PROC SQL.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I assumed that  you still need to do merge before updating, in an interim dataset. And only after that update oracle table with prepared data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138104/error-in-modify-statement-in-data-step-ora-01403
Can you please comment?